# Setting Data-Parent and HREF dynamically in a for-loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Previously to create Accordion controls I used to use this piece of code:

```
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMessagesSetup">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMessagesSetup" href="#collapseMessagesSetup">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                                    Message Setup
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseMessagesSetup" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div>
                                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE in here</p>
                                <p style="background-color: red"> Someting ELSE2 in here</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

or as seen here: [Bootplay Live Demo](http://www.bootply.com/p2WONtGkEK)

Now I still want to use my example but in this page I have a for-each loop so I need to create these at run-time.

The items I need to put variables there in order for this to work are

```
id="accordionMessagesSetup"
data-parent="#accordionMessagesSetup"
href="#collapseMessagesSetup"
id="collapseMessagesSetup"
```

How can I initialize those in a for-each loop a mode using Razor? 
Imagine you have whatever property you like to do it in the model.

Comment: id = @Model.PrimaryKeyFieldForExample .. my more confusion is for when there is that "#" , don't know how to do that

Comment: `id='@String.Format("#{0}", Model.PrimaryKeyFieldForExample)'`should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue you are/will likely run into is Razor parsing. When you try to use a Razor variable in the middle of some bit of text, often Razor cannot determine where the variable name ends. For example, if you were to do something like:

```
<div id="accordion@Model.IdMessageSetup">
```

Razor thinks it needs to look for a property on the model named `IdMessageSetup`, when actually, you just wanted `Id`. The easiest way to fix this is to wrap the variable in paranthesis:

```
<div id="accordion@(Model.Id)MessageSetup">
```

Now, it's clear which part is the variable. As far as adding the `#` sign goes, I'm not really sure what the confusion is there. You just put it where it needs to go:

```
<a href="#collapse@(Model.Id)MessagesSetup">
```

Nothing special required.